# Not a valid indentifier - Apache Maven

Tags: bash, maven

I'm trying to setup Apache Maven for Red Hat AMQ, but the `README.md` file says the following:

> Installing Maven   ----------------
>
> 1) Unpack the archive where you would like to store the binaries,
>   e.g.:
>
> ```
> Unix-based operating systems (Linux, Solaris and Mac OS X)
>   tar zxvf apache-maven-3.x.y.tar.gz
> Windows
>   unzip apache-maven-3.x.y.zip
> ```
>
> 2) A directory called "apache-maven-3.x.y" will be created.
>
> 3) Add the bin directory to your PATH, e.g.:
>
> ```
> Unix-based operating systems (Linux, Solaris and Mac OS X)
>   export PATH=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.x.y/bin:$PATH
> Windows
>   set PATH="c:\program files\apache-maven-3.x.y\bin";%PATH%
> ```
>
> 4) Make sure JAVA_HOME is set to the location of your JDK
>
> 5) Run "mvn --version" to verify that it is correctly installed.

Im stuck at the 3rd part, when you have to put the path for the export.

This is what I type in my bash:

```sh
$ export PATH= ~/Downloads/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:$PATH
```

As result, I'm getting the following error:

```sh
-bash: export: `/home/amq-broker/Downloads/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:': not a valid identifier
```

What's wrong?

A screenshot from all of this:
[image: practical result]

Comment: Can you update your question with screenshot of the command line showing the command and error? (Just want to rule out any typos in the command you have mentioned in the question)

Comment: going to update it in a minute

Comment: Can you try using the full path instead of the ~ ?

Comment: Also I see a space on after your PATH=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space after `PATH=` in this statement `export PATH= ~....`.

You should also use the full path, not the relative path.

Try this, `export PATH=/home/amq-broker/Downloads/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:$PATH`